# How to show combined overall accuracy for a multi-ouput model in Keras?

Tags: cnn, accuracy, multilabel-classification, metric, multi-output

I have a model of the following structure. It has 6 outputs. Given an image, the model predicts classes of 6 different components from the image.
[image: Multi output keras model]

The metrics I used are:

[image: Metrics used]

As you can see it outputs an overall combined loss and separate losses for different outputs. But there is no combined accuracy score. What I want is a combined accuracy score ( Which will consider a sample is correct if all the output labels are correct). How can I calculate overall combined accuracy for my multioutput model?

[image: Ouput of the model]

Answer (score 0):

Tensroflow has a built-in metric for [accuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy). Add this line to 'metrices' in your code:

```
'acc':[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()]
```